# Fetching results from Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I have this:

```
source_list = ['a', 'b']
target_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
my_dict = {
    'a': ['e'],
    'b': ['f', 'd'],
    'e': ['g'],
    'f': ['t', 'h'],
    'd': ['x'],
    'g': ['x'],
    't': ['y'],
    'h': ['z']
}
```

I am trying to use the `source_list` to get the keys from dictionary `my_dict` until I reach the values as in target list and also get the iteration and use it as key in output dictionary:

Expecting output as

```
{0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']},
 1: {'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x']},
 2: {'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}}
```

I have written the code:

```
from collections import deque

source_list = ['a', 'b']
target_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
my_dict = {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd'], 'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x'], 'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}

result_dict = {}
queue = deque([(0, my_dict)])

while queue:
    iteration, current_dict = queue.popleft()
    result_dict[iteration] = {key: current_dict[key] for key in source_list if key in current_dict}

    next_dict = {item: my_dict.get(item, []) for key in result_dict[iteration] for item in current_dict[key]}
    if any(target_value in next_dict for target_value in target_list):
        queue.append((iteration + 1, next_dict))

print(result_dict)
```

Getting output:

```
{0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']}}
```

Comment: maybe write it as normal `for`-loops - so you could add `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables

Comment: frankly, I don't understand expected result. Why `[0]` has only 2 elements  `a` and `b`? Why `[1]` has 3 elements?

Comment: plz check now if its fine

Comment: I think the logic is messed up: `any(target_value ... in target_list)` maybe should be `any(target_value ... not in target_list)`. Not sure I understand the task or the algorithm; anyway, use common sense to judge whether this logic is correct.

Comment: I am trying it out as i am new to coding

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/509868) with answers

Comment: @furas I guess you just look up keys in the dictionary, take their values and and use them as keys again. Starting keys are in `source_list` and loop finishes when all keys are in `target_list`. In first iteration the keys `a` and `b` give you `e` and `f, d`. In second iteration the keys `e`, `f` and `d` give you `g` and `t, h` (and `x` but I guess we skip it since it is in the target list). In third iteration all the keys `g`, `t` and `h` have their corresponding values in the `target_list`. Stop.

Comment: @Jeyekomon now I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):

```
def bfs(source, target, graph):
    queue = deque((0, node) for node in source)
    target_set = set(target)
    seen = set()
    result = {}

    while queue:
        level, node = queue.popleft()
        neighbors = graph[node]
        result.setdefault(level, {})[node] = neighbors.copy()

        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor in seen or neighbor in target_set:
                continue
            seen.add(neighbor)
            queue.append((level + 1, neighbor))

    return result
```

The `seen` is used here to prevent duplicate nodes from enqueueing. If `my_dict` can be guaranteed to be a tree (i.e. the graph has no cycles), it can be remove.

Output:

```
In [_]: source_list = ['a', 'b']
   ...: target_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
   ...: my_dict = {
   ...:     'a': ['e'],
   ...:     'b': ['f', 'd'],
   ...:     'e': ['g'],
   ...:     'f': ['t', 'h'],
   ...:     'd': ['x'],
   ...:     'g': ['x'],
   ...:     't': ['y'],
   ...:     'h': ['z']
   ...: }

In [_]: bfs(source_list, target_list, my_dict)
Out[_]:
{0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']},
 1: {'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x']},
 2: {'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}}
```

---

A slightly faster version is to use an internal loop to build the dict for each layer, record the node at the end of the queue before the loop, and then collect the neighbors of nodes in this layer until the recorded node is dequequed:

```
def solution(source, target, graph):
    target_set = set(target)
    result = {}

    seen = set(source)
    queue = deque(source)
    level = 0
    while queue:
        result[level] = build_level_dict(graph, queue, seen, target_set)
        level += 1

    return result


def build_level_dict(graph, queue, seen, target_set):
    tail = queue[-1]
    level_dict = {}
    while True:
        node = queue.popleft()
        neighbors = graph[node]
        level_dict[node] = neighbors.copy()

        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor in seen or neighbor in target_set:
                continue
            seen.add(neighbor)
            queue.append(neighbor)

        if node == tail:
            return level_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the desired distance dictionary recursively:

```
def distances(nodes, sources, targets):
    def _distances(level, sources, targets=set(targets)):
        for source in sources:
            if source not in targets:
                result.setdefault(level, {})[source] = children = nodes[source]
                _distances(level + 1, children)
    result = {}
    _distances(0, sources)
    return result
```

so that:

```
distances(my_dict, source_list, target_list)
```

returns:

```
{0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']}, 1: {'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x']}, 2: {'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/EiynOP

Answer (score -2):

```py
from collections import deque

source_list = ['a', 'b']
target_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
my_dict = {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd'], 'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x'], 'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}

result_dict = {}
queue = deque([(0, my_dict)])

while queue:
    iteration, current_dict = queue.popleft()
    result_dict[iteration] = {key: current_dict[key] for key in source_list if key in current_dict}

    next_dict = {item: my_dict.get(item, []) for key in result_dict[iteration] for item in my_dict[key]}
    if any(target_value in next_dict for target_value in target_list):
        queue.append((iteration + 1, next_dict))

print(result_dict)
```

Comment: it still gives output for one iteration i.e {0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']}}
I am expecting its as {0: {'a': ['e'], 'b': ['f', 'd']},
 1: {'e': ['g'], 'f': ['t', 'h'], 'd': ['x']},
 2: {'g': ['x'], 't': ['y'], 'h': ['z']}}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**